# Очистить многоуровневый массив от лишнего

Tags: php, массивы

Предыстория: Пытаюсь получить список комментаторов с большого количества постов.

Вопрос: Как можно очистить полученный массив от всего лишнего, чтобы на выходе получить только массив с всеми ["id"] (Только тот который лежит в ["profiles"] ?

Пытался при помощи циклов внутри циклов, но далеко не уехал, быстро запутался.

```
array(1) {
  ["response"]=>
  array(4) {
    ["count"]=>
    int(4)
    ["items"]=>
    array(4) {
      [0]=>
      array(4) {
        ["id"]=>
        int(4001)
        ["from_id"]=>
        int(359842340)
        ["date"]=>
        int(1530078966)
        ["text"]=>
        string(10) "Текст коментария"
      }
      [1]=>
      array(4) {
        ["id"]=>
        int(4002)
        ["from_id"]=>
        int(359842340)
        ["date"]=>
        int(1530078979)
        ["text"]=>
        string(45) "Текст коментария"
      }
      [2]=>
      array(4) {
        ["id"]=>
        int(4003)
        ["from_id"]=>
        int(359842340)
        ["date"]=>
        int(1530079019)
        ["text"]=>
        string(78) "Текст коментария"
      }
      [3]=>
      array(4) {
        ["id"]=>
        int(4015)
        ["from_id"]=>
        int(165517974)
        ["date"]=>
        int(1530346405)
        ["text"]=>
        string(150) "Текст коментария"
      }
    }
    ["profiles"]=>
    array(2) {
      [0]=>
      array(8) {
        ["id"]=>
        int(165517974)
        ["first_name"]=>
        string(14) "Дмитрий"
        ["last_name"]=>
        string(29) "Новожилов-Шухов"
        ["sex"]=>
        int(2)
        ["screen_name"]=>
        string(10) "grim_jager"
        ["photo_50"]=>
        string(69) "https://pp.userapi.com/c844720/v844720372/8decc/RKhvEtIoWaQ.jpg?ava=1"
        ["photo_100"]=>
        string(69) "https://pp.userapi.com/c844720/v844720372/8decb/Sy_iO9EiqbY.jpg?ava=1"
        ["online"]=>
        int(0)
      }
      [1]=>
      array(8) {
        ["id"]=>
        int(359842340)
        ["first_name"]=>
        string(14) "Радимир"
        ["last_name"]=>
        string(14) "Павелич"
        ["sex"]=>
        int(2)
        ["screen_name"]=>
        string(16) "radimir_pavelich"
        ["photo_50"]=>
        string(69) "https://pp.userapi.com/c845221/v845221606/4e459/19THGOMLHJ8.jpg?ava=1"
        ["photo_100"]=>
        string(69) "https://pp.userapi.com/c845221/v845221606/4e458/UiUrY-ZOGYs.jpg?ava=1"
        ["online"]=>
        int(0)
      }
    }
    ["groups"]=>
    array(0) {
    }
  }
}
```

Вот код цикла которым получаю эти массивы комментариев:

```
for ($i=0; $i<=count($arrays); $i++) {

$query = file_get_contents("https://api.vk.com/method/wall.getComments?owner_id=-".$group_id."&extended=1&post_id=".$ids[$i]."&need_likes=0&count=100&extended=1&v=5.80&access_token=".$access_token);

//Вбиваем массивы с комментариями в единый массив
$result = json_decode ($query,true);

$pIds = array_column($result['response']['profiles'], 'id');
vardump($pIds);
//usleep(450000);

};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`array_column()`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.array-column.php) вам в помощь

```
$pIds =  array_column($data['response']['profiles'], 'id');
```

Comment: Здравствуйте, решение хорошее но у меня получается реализовать его только с 1 массивом, а мой цикл выводит сразу много таких массивов и каждый нужно получается прогонять этой функцией?

Comment: ну да. Если у вас массив `$array` содержащий элементы (вложенные массивы), как в вопросе то `$result = array_map(function($data){ return array_column(....)}, $array);`. Если потом надо получить единый список уникальных id то добавить `$result = array_unique(array_merge(...$result))`

Comment: а если подсчитать сколько раз встречаются то `array_count_values` вместо `array_unique`

Comment: А можно пример с подобным массивом и этими функциями? А то у меня не получается с моим. Буду очень благодарен!

Answer (score 0):

Посмотрим укороченный массив, идентичный структуре вашему

```
$array = [
    'response' => [
        'count' => 4,
        'items' => [
            [
                'id' => 1337,
                'text' => 'test0'
            ],
            [
                'id' => 228,
                'text' => 'text2'
            ]
        ],
        'profiles' => [
            [
                'id' => 165517974,
                'first_name' => 'Дмитрий',
                'last_name' => 'Новожилов-Шухов'
            ],
            [
                'id' => 359842340,
                'first_name' => 'Радимир',
                'last_name' => 'Павелич'
            ]
        ]
    ]
];
```

Поместить список всех `id` из подмассива `profiles` в отдельный массив можно сделать при помощи цикла `foreach`.

```
foreach ($array['response']['profiles'] as $key => $value) {
    $new_array [] = $value['id'];
}

print_r($new_array);
```

Далее смотрим результат

```
Array
(
    [0] => 165517974
    [1] => 359842340
)
```

Comment: Здравствуйте, там же 2 массива profiles с 2 id'ами в каждом, конечный результат должен быть Array
(
    [0] => 165517974
    [1] => 359842340
    [2] => 224864618
    [3] => 432658051
)

Comment: @CoffeeinTime, где вы увидели `224864618` и `432658051`?